# Why do gnome calculator and terminal behave differently when launched with os.system()?

Tags: python, shell

My final goal is to start from a Python script another Python script which uses a Terminal as user dialog GUI to ask for file names and then get by that another script on its exit to the Terminal printed selected file names.

I have tried to use `os.system()` and `subprocess.Popen()` in all to me known possible variants but failed to achieve my goal. Querying the internet for hours and days did not help. The issues with inter-process communication and redirection of stdout and stdin seem to be very hard to explain.

Using `os.system("gnome-terminal")` I can launch a terminal without blocking the Python script and using PyAutoGUI I should be able to launch the other script in the Terminal shell, but I still have no clue how to approach the problem with getting the result printed by the the other script to the command line.

On my way to solving the above problem by myself I would like to improve my understanding how launching applications and redirection of stdin and stdout work by knowing the answer to the question stated in the title.

Here the code:

```
import os, sys
os.system("gnome-terminal")
print('''OK after os.system("gnome-terminal") ''')
sys.exit()
```

which starts a Terminal, prints and exits.

And here the code which is blocked after launching the calculator:

```
import os, sys
os.system("gnome-calculator")
print('''OK after os.system("gnome-calculator") ''')
sys.exit()
```

failing to print 'hanging' until the calculator window is closed.

---

UPDATE considering the hint about process ID of spawned applications given in the comments by *bigkeefer*. I have tried to find out what is the difference between gnome-calculator and gnome-terminal and SciTE (which also does not block). It seems that applications already running and not allowing multiple instances don't block. The gnome-terminal seem to be only one instance for all the opened windows, so it is always already there if a new one is launched by a shell command. This explains the difference in behavior I have observed, but ... still does not answer the question, *why* is it that way?

```
  ~ $ gnome-calculator &
[1] 18115
  ~ $ gnome-calculator &
[2] 18122
[1]   Done                    gnome-calculator
  ~ $ SciTE &
[3] 18141
[2]   Done                    gnome-calculator
  ~ $ SciTE &
[4] 18142
[3]   Done                    SciTE
  ~ $ SciTE &
[5] 18150
[4]   Done                    SciTE
  ~ $ SciTE
[5]+  Done                    SciTE
  ~ $ SciTE
  ~ $ SciTE
  ~ $ SciTE &
[1] 18183
  ~ $ SciTE &
[2] 18187
[1]   Done                    SciTE
  ~ $ gnome-terminal
[2]+  Done                    SciTE
  ~ $
```

Most weird appears to be the feedback from the shell about SciTE after launching gnome-terminal (see last three lines).

Comment: Try `os.system("gnome-calculator > /dev/null &")` in case it's waiting for the output.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know how to make this call non-blocking. What I don't know is how does it come that applications behave differently? What is the underlying mechanism that results in different behavior of different applications? I thought that is necessary to redirect stdout and stderr both (also `2> /dev/null`) in case there is eventually an output on stderr, but gnome-calculator does not output anything and is blocking anyway.

Comment: Started from a command line in the shell the gnome-calculator blocks. Using & it does not block anymore, but the shell outputs `[1] 17745` . What does it mean? With > /dev/null the shell gives:  `[3] 17778
[2]   Done   gnome-calculator > /dev/null` ...

Comment: 17745 will be a new process ID (pid) as you have asked the shell to "fork" (by using the ampersand) gnome calculator. Try ps aux | grep pid to see the results.

Comment: This may be useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27666/why-do-some-commands-hang-the-terminal-until-theyve-finished

Comment: @bigkeefer : thanks for your comment. Yes, I have been though that link already, but the accepted answer suggests that the Terminal will 'hang' on all launched applications, but it doesn't.

Comment: @bigkeefer : Yes ... it is the process ID (pid) shown in the shell, but ... for already running applications which do not allow multiple instances the shown new process ID is not assigned as the application keeps its old ID. So it is not generally true. And sometimes there is only a plus sign instead of the ID. And ... what does the number in the square brackets mean?

Comment: Yes, apologies, "fork" was not the right  word to use. I quoted it to mean it kind of simulates forking (but I was not clear at all on that). The shell is actually running it in the background (so it's still attached to the shell and stdout and stderr will still come to your terminal (even if you're typing something at the time!). It's actually Unix job control. The numbers in square brackets mean the job number. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes

Comment: `gnome-terminal` forks itself and returns immediately (though there is an option to *not* do that), while `gnome-calculator` does not. This has nothing to do with Python or the shell used by `os.system`; it's just a matter of how the program you are executing was written.

Comment: With `nohup`  there are no error messages from gnome-calculator (just type 'fgfg' instead of digits to trigger error messages) shown in the shell. With `disown` the calculator survives the death of the shell, but the shell still prints its error messages in the shell. So disown is not really disown and nohup is not only nohup but 'disowns' stronger than disown.

Answer (score 0):

I can't (yet) provide any details about the *why* it is the way it is, but I can (with help of the comments to my question) explain what is the difference between the gnome-calculator and the gnome-terminal application which *may*  cause the observed different blocking behavior.

Launching a gnome-terminal does not launch a new instance of the Terminal with a new process ID because the Terminal application ( the gnome-terminal-server ) is already running and does not allow multiple instances of itself (only multiple windows). There will be always only one gnome-terminal-server running.

Launching a gnome-calculator launches a new instance of the Calculator with another process ID. Gnome Calculator allows multiple independent instances of itself to be created.

Generally it seems that applications which are already running and don't allow multiple instances of itself don't block where applications which are not yet running or which allow multiple instances of itself block.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is that **all** applications executed from the terminal actually behave exactly the same way ("blocking" the shell) until they are terminated; either by the user, or by the program exiting itself: be that cleanly (exit status 0), with an error (exit status not 0) or crashing).

As discussed in the comments, you can use job control and other things to work around this if required (although these days most people just fire up another tab etcetera in their terminal). You can, however, also completely detach from the shell (with bash, for example, other shells vary) by using:

```
gnome-calculator 2> /dev/null & disown
```

With the behaviour seen with gnome-terminal, it turns out it's because it executes and actually spawns gnome-terminal-server (or, presumably, tells it to open another terminal window if it is already running) and then terminates itself. Thus your shell "returns to you" (no longer "blocked") because the program (gnome-terminal) you ran has (almost) instantly exited (with status 0 in this case) because its job was to actually either briefly communicate with another program or run that program (which is now not attached to the shell as a result. i.e. it's been forked by gnome-terminal). e.g.:

```
~$ gnome-terminal &
[2] 4313
~$ ps aux | grep terminal
4319  3.7  0.7 558332 56236 ?        Ssl  11:49   0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
[2]+  Done                    gnome-terminal
```

gnome-terminal executes (pid 4313), spawns gnome-server-terminal (if not already running, asks for another terminal window if it is I assume) and then terminates itself. `ps 4313` returns nothing which, with this experiment output, is now not surprising as we can see that job 2 has indeed already ended. However, that's not how it looked to us originally of course! (Or to anyone taken at "face value"/on the surface.)

Once all gnome terminal windows are closed, the server process stops running too (until gnome-terminal is executed again).

I would suspect that applications, that don't allow multiple instances of themselves, actually initially execute in the shell, detect that an instance is already running and simply instantly terminate. Thus not "blocking" because they are actually no longer running. (Your shell would have been blocked for a few milliseconds maybe.)

Depending on the app, it may or may not display a message (stderr) telling the user this. If it doesn't display one, it looks like it's not blocking because its executed and almost instantly terminated again.

**Further information edit:**

Just a note that I'm no great expert at this, but this is how I understand it to be...

Adding an ampersand to the end of a shell command makes it a background task, giving control of the shell prompt straight back to you, so that you can continue working without waiting for the job to finish (and thus for your shell prompt to come back). The command you just ran, as a result, is managed by the shell [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) system. You can keep doing your SysAdmin stuff or whatever while it does, this and it will tell you when a background job is done (this is the `[2]+ done` message you see for example). This is not particularly useful in our examples here, but imagine running a find command for one example that might take hours on a big filesystem. Run that in the background and you can keep working while it does its stuff.

`stdout` and `stderr` however still come back to your terminal (unless you redirect it). The shell is looking after all these jobs and they will all die if the shell dies. Which brings us on to `nohup`.

If, for example, a terminal window is closed then it receives a [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (stands for signal hangup -- it dates back to serial line days! Most, if not all, modern shells now will intercept this signal and basically decide/figure out what to do about its running jobs before terminating). There are other ways to send it as well but this can lead to a relatively big topic so, suffice to say for this context, that running a command with `nohup` in front of it tells the shell to ignore input and save stdout to a file instead for that command whilst also making the command "immune" to hangups/disconnections. e.g.

```
~$ nohup find /usr/bin/libre*
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
~$ cat nohup.out 
/usr/bin/libreoffice
~$
```

(note that the prompt is returned instantly to you after running the first command). Anything executed with `nohup` also gets managed by the job system.

(You will also see a demo of how the shell can handle SIGHUP in the following example which includes what `disown` does.)

In regards to the difference between just using the ampersand and `gnome-calculator 2> /dev/null & disown` there is an example that you can do in your terminal:

```
~$ gnome-calculator &
[1] 6058
```

Now leave calculator running but close your terminal by clicking the X of its window. gnome-calculator will die with it.

Open your terminal and run the above again but this time press CTRL-D to close the terminal. This time you should see `exit` in your shell for maybe two seconds and then it dies -- but calculator keeps running. Those couple of seconds is your shell intercepting the signal (CTRL-D) and deciding to disown its job processes (if possible) so they survive before it terminates.

Now run:

```
~$ gnome-calculator 2> /dev/null & disown
[1] 7068
```

And close your terminal by clicking its X in its window. Calculator will survive this time as you have explicitly told the shell to detach it from itself when it was first executed. So the above command tells the shell to ignore both stdout and stderr, run the calc in the background but also immediately disown it (basically making calc its own process no longer "tied" to the shell). This way calc survives regardless of what happens to the shell (be it different hangup signals to the shell or the shell crashing etcetera).

Comment: How should a Python script look like to be able to demonstrate the different behavior of `pyscript.py 2> /dev/null & disown` compared to only `pyscript.py &`? I can't see a difference when running `gnome-calculator` between these two options. To make things a bit more complicated ... there is also `nohup` to consider for use in this context placing it at the start of the command. Is there a way to demonstrate somehow what does what?

Comment: I will add to my answer to hopefully help with your questions.

Comment: What I have still problem with is to understand how it can be that the terminal receives and displays input from more than one source of data. If I type when it is "blocked" it still echoes my input to the window, but suspends execution of it until the other process is finished. Are the stdin, stdout and stderr somehow shared and available to user input and the spawned applications at the same time?

Comment: This is due to the very, very long history of UNIX  (the fact that we're still effectively using it many decades later is testament to how awesome UNIX design was in the first place) and therefore effectively Linux and also MacOS and namely the difference between terminal emulators, consoles and shells etc. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

Comment: When it's "blocked" that is the shell still "doing its stuff". i.e. It's still busy executing the last thing you told it to do. You can still type whilst it's doing this because that's your terminal emulator/tty doing its job and therefore letting you type regardless. The shell is simply "ignoring" you at this point. When the shell finishes that job the stuff you typed into the terminal (emulator)/tty gets "picked up" by the shell and it executes that in sequence...